# Formal loop space in algebraic geometry

Tags: reference-request, derived-algebraic-geometry

Does anyone have a reference or an explanation about the relationship between the formal loop space defined for affine schemes via $LX\left(R\right) = X\left(R\left(\left(t\right)\right)\right)$ (or Kapranov’s version with nilpotent elements of negative degree) and the formal completion of the (derived, in the appropriate sense) object $X\times_{X\times X} X$ around the diagonal embedding of $X$? (Everything in characteristic zero). Thanks!

Comment: They ultimately arise from very different notions of circles - the scheme $\mathbb{G}_m$ and the simplicial set $\Delta^1/\partial \Delta^1$.